# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in [File] on line 28

Tags: php, html

i have been making a login form with PHP. And i keep on getting the error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in [File Dir] on line 28
>   I have tried looking at other forms but they haven't worked

Code:

```
<?php

require('config.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

}else{

  $form = <<<EOT
  <form action="register.php" method="POST">
  First Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
  Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br />
  UserName: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
  Email: <input type="text" name="email1" /><br />
  Confirm Email: <input type="text" name="email2" /><br />
  Password: <input type="password" name="pass1" /><br />
  Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="pass2" /><br />
  <input type="sumbit" value="Register" name="submit" />
  </form>
  EOT;
  echo $form;

}

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be no other character before & after `EOT;`.
PHP [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) manual says:

> It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;). That means especially that the identifier may not be indented, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon.

```
$form = <<<EOT
  <form action="register.php" method="POST">
  ...
  </form>
EOT;
// No other character is allowed around EOT;
```

Comment: What do u mean "No Space Allowed

Comment: @GhostCyborg No other character is allowed before & after the closing identifier `EOT;` -including spaces/tabs. In other words, the heredoc closing line needs to be exact `EOT;` without any indentations nor trailing characters.